# Flash rig in movie clip

Tags: flash, animation, movie, clip

I built a flash rig and I have it contained in a movie clip so I can use movie clip effects. Is there a way I can have the corresponding frame inside the movie clip display on the main stage. I'm tired of publishing and checking.

Comment: Now I've used the term rig before, but never in the context of Flash. What is a Flash rig?

Comment: You use a combination of the IK bones and symbols inside movie clips with the registration points moved for a faux FK animation. In short you build a character rig.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, now I get it! Sorry I can't help though, I'm more of a Flex/AS3 guy. But now that you mention it, I think I've wondered about the same type of thing, the few times I've used the Flash authoring tool.